# In ASP.NET Large resource file vs separates resource files?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, localization, resources, internationalization

We have a big application and we are trying to find out whats the difference between having a huge resource file for each language or having the resources in separate files.

Is there a hit in performance in any of the strategies?

What are the pros and cons for each one?

Comment: Can you describe a bit more what kinds of resources we are talking about here?

Comment: As the question is tagged with "localization" and "internationalization", it sounds like the resources would mostly be string content.

Comment: A couple weeks ago when I was doing some performance profiling using the built-in Visual Studio tool, I did notice that global resource management on the web side did take up a fair chunk of resources. This project had resources divided into separate files. Maybe 150-200 of them. You might be able to run a test using the profiling tool to get a comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do mean huge, then of course performance would be one issue. But outside of this, see this related question for a justification in favour of keeping resources separate: [Globalization in ASP.net MVC (Resource file per View vs Domain)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896463/globalization-in-asp-net-mvc-resource-file-per-view-vs-domain/10918035#10918035)